# "Source folder is not a Java project" error in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to import maven project into eclipse 4.2 version.Its not importing the project properly. Its giving me error "Source folder is not a Java project" while I am trying to create a new call in it. Even ctrl+mouse click is also not working. I don't understand the problem. Even when I right click on project and select build path it shows me no action available. Anyone face the same issue

Answer (score 87, accepted):

In the maven project directory try

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

that may do the trick.

Comment: It 2015 now and Eclipse still doesn't do that when creating a new Maven project from within Eclipse? Just poor.

Comment: It's 2017 and Eclipse doesn't give a damn to this bug.

Comment: I just ran into this myself after importing a maven project. I also had to do a mvn clean

Comment: It's 2019 and Eclipse doesn't give a damn to this bug.

Comment: I restarted STS (Based on eclipse) and then it picked up that it is a java project.

Comment: Alternative to this solution is

Right click your project > Maven > Update Project

Comment: We are in 2020 and Eclipse doesn't even care.

Comment: It's 2021, this is so old school

Comment: It's 2022, this is so old school

Comment: It's 2023 and the issue still exists.

Comment: It's fast approaching 2024, and guess what....

Answer (score 55):

I ran into the same issue and fixed it by converting my project to [faceted form](https://eclipse.org/proposals/fproj/).

Right click your project > *Properties* > *Project Facets* > *Convert to Faceted Form*, and select Java.

[image: Java Project Facets]

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem... But you just need to update "source Folder" to correct source "src/main/java" from whatever mentioned in the pop up:

[[image: Updating the Source Folder in Eclipse]]

Answer (score 6):

Either turn your project into Eclipse project, using `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, or install Maven Integration for Eclipse plugins, like [m2eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/), and import project as a Maven project.

Answer (score 6):

I got the same error in a slightly different context (Indigo with m2eclipse):

I imported a multi-module (1 jar module and 1 war module) maven project into Eclipse. Everything worked fine (clean, install OK) until I tried to add a new class to one of the modules and got the "Source Folder is not a Java project" error.

I solved this by opening the properties on the parent project and selecting the following Project Facets:
Java
Dynamic Web Module

This solved the problem. My guess is that, because the parent project for a multi-module project has pom packaging (`<packaging>pom</packaging>`), Eclipse doesn't know what kind of projects the parent project encloses (i.e. if the packaging were jar, it would know that it's a java project; if the packaging were war, it would know that it's a static or dynamic web module, etc.)

This is just my guess, but the fix worked for me, and it makes sense.

Comment: I had the same issue with maven multi module projects and this pretty much solved it. Thanks :)

Comment: A similar thing just happened to me. I had accidentally left a `<packaging>pom</packaging>` designation on the child POMs in a multi-module product. I didn't need to change any facets—I merely removed the project from Eclipse, corrected the POMs, and re-imported the project into Eclipse.

Answer (score 5):

for those who already see java selected, uncheck and check it again. 
select apply to override the existing setttings. finally it works !

Right click your project > Properties > Project Facets > Convert to Faceted Form, and select Java

Answer (score 5):

Right click your `project > Maven > Update Project`

This step will add your project so the issue resolves easily.

Answer (score 3):

mvn eclipse:eclipse
 will resolve this problem. convert to maven project.

Answer (score 2):

open cmd and run the following command in the folder of your project-

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

This did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

I had this error because I tried to create a new Project by doing "Ctrl+N", typing "Project" on the Wizard's input label and then just pushing "Enter" until it was created.
I solved this by typing **"Java Project"** instead of just "Project".
You can also create a JAVA PROJECT by going to File > New > Java Project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having maven project and you are getting this error. You can follow below steps.

1. Right click on the project and select **properties**.
2. Then click on **Project Natures**
3. In the dialogue box, click on **Add** and in the warning click on **OK**.
4. Filter **java** in the popup box and click on **OK**.
5. Click on **apply and close**.

It will add java nature to your maven project and you will not get this error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project > Properties > Project Facets > Convert to Faceted Form, select Java,  and apply&close